# Differential equations having different solutions near different points (according to wolfram)

Tags: calculus

[image]

So, I know this differential equation is homogenous and I tried solving it by using the homogenous substitution $ y=xt$ , However in one of the steps I had to integrate something with a cubic in denominator

$$\int \frac{ u^2 +1}{-u^3 - u^2 - u + 1} du$$

So this integral comes up and I don't know how to solve it. What exactly could be wrong? why does this solution look so convuluted and having different 'solutions' near different points?

Edit:
[Unsolvable Differential Equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443753/unsolvable-differential-equation)

I found this which is similar, however I don't think the solution which was given to this is quite right

Comment: Really similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given homogenius ODE is
$$\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} = \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}.$$
Can be applied substitution
$$x= (u+1)y,\tag1$$
$$y\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dy} = -u-1+\dfrac{(u+1)^2+1}{(u+1)^2-1},$$
$$y\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dy}=-u+\dfrac{2}{(u+1)^2-1},$$

$$\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y}=-\dfrac{u^2+2u}{u^3+2u^2-2}{\mathrm du}.\tag2$$
Since the denominator of RHS(2) [has a root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%5E3%2B2u%5E2-2)
$$r=\dfrac13\left(\sqrt[3]{19+\sqrt{297}}+\sqrt[3]{19-\sqrt{297}}-2\right)\approx 0.83928\,67552\,14161,\tag3$$
\begin{align}
&27(r^3+2r^2-2) = (3r+2)^3 - 12(3r+2) - 38\\
&=  \left(\sqrt[3]{19+\sqrt{297}\,}\,+\sqrt[3]{19-\sqrt{297}\,}\,\right)^3
-12\left(\sqrt[3]{19+\sqrt{297}}+\sqrt[3]{19-\sqrt{297}}\right)-38\\
&= \left(3\sqrt[3]{19+\sqrt{297}\,}\,\sqrt[3]{19-\sqrt{297}\,}-12\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{19+\sqrt{297}\,}\,+\sqrt[3]{19-\sqrt{297}\,}\,\right)\\
&= \left(3\sqrt[3]{64}-12\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{19+\sqrt{297}\,}\,+\sqrt[3]{19-\sqrt{297}\,}\,\right) = 0,
\end{align}
then
$$u^3+2u^2-2 = (u-r)(u^2+(r+2)u+r^2+2r),$$
$$R(u)=\dfrac{u^2+2u}{u^3+2u^2-2}=\dfrac A{u-r}+\dfrac{B(2u+r+2)}{u^2+(r+2)u+r^2+2r}
+\dfrac{C}{u^2+(r+2)u+r^2+2r},$$
where
$$A = \lim_{u\to r}(u-r)R(u) = \dfrac{r^2+2r}{3r^2+4r} = \dfrac{r+2}{3r+4},$$
$$A+2B = \lim_{u\to \infty}uR(u) = 1,\quad B=\dfrac{r+1}{3r+4},$$
$$\dfrac {B-A}r+\dfrac C{r^2+2r} = R(0)=0,\quad C=\dfrac{r+2}{3r+4},$$
$$u^2+(r+2)u+r^2+2r = \left(u+\dfrac{r+2}2\right)^2+\dfrac{(r+2)(3r-2)}4.$$

Then from $(2)$ should
$$(3r+4)\ln \mathrm{const}|y| = (r+2)\ln|u-r|+(r+1)\ln|u^2+(r+2)u+r^2+2r|\\
+2\sqrt{\dfrac{r+2}{3r-2}}\arctan\dfrac{2u+r+2}{\sqrt{(r+2)(3r-2)}},$$
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{\small C_1|y|^{3r+4}|u-r||u^3+2u^2-2|^{r+1} = \exp\left(2\sqrt{\dfrac{r+2}{3r-2}}\arctan\dfrac{2u+r+2}{\sqrt{(r+2)(3r-2)}}\right)}},\tag4$$
where $C_1$ is the arbitrary constant.

Formulas $(1),(3),(4)$ present the common solution of the given ODE.

Comment: I have one question, why does wolf ram give me different solutions neear different points?

Comment: @DDD4C4U It looks as WA used the intervals method to avoid the function |a|.

Comment: what happens at |a|

Comment: what is |a| , i couldnt figure from your solution

Comment: @DDD4C4U I've meant the absolute value.   But I shoud think once more.

Comment: @DDD4C4U There is the fractions expansion over the complex roots $r_i.$ And then WA uses the antiderivatives for $\frac1{u-r_i}.$

Comment: I see, from what I know the fraction decomposistion changes in the complex plane, is this related to that?

Comment: @DDD4C4U There are three terms. Every term uses the root for the antiderivative and at the same time - for the coefficient evaluating.

Comment: why did you put  $ x= (u+1)y$

Comment: @DDD4C4U To simplify the denominator.